# Controlling RGB led strip each color with a switch

Tags: led-strip, rgb

I am creating a picture frame that will have RGB led strip surrounding the frame. There is no room for controller.

Is it possible to wire  a switch between every color cable so I can manualy turn on and off each color. 
I would drill the 3 switches into the frame and there the user can assign the desired color.

Do switches need to be rated for higher current?
The total lenght of the led strip is about 1.5m so it doesnt take much.

Only problem i can think of is that, when I turn multible colors on, the  power/voltage  will split and the strenght of light will decrease.

Is it true?

Comment: We'd just be guessing until you provide some documentation on the LED strip you're using.  Edit in a link to the spec, or at least a part number.

Comment: Okay, I will arrive home tomorrow evening and then I can update with futher info.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can connect a switch between each color and ground (assuming you have a common anode led strip). Most common switches at an auto parts store can do 10 Amps, more than you should need. At 1.5m, you are probably looking at less than an amp for each channel/color.

Of course, you will be limited to 8 color combinations.

You should not see any decrease in light intensity at 1.5 meters even with all 3 channels on, *as long as your power supply can do 12V at how ever many amps are needed for your power strip*.

Side note, the controllers for these can be very small and use radio or IR remotes. They should fit in the picture frame or can hang off the wire if you use an extension.

Answer (score -1):

> Only problem i can think of is that, when I turn multible colors on, the power/voltage will split and the strenght of light will decrease.

No. The voltage goes to each color in parallel. If your supply can support the current needed, the strips will all see the same voltage.

Comment: I think your "No" is a pretty bold statement. You are assuming not only that the power supply **can** provide enough current but also that its load rejection is perfect. Until the OP provides information about the power supply I wouldn't make that assumption.